# Compare two files in bash

Tags: string, bash, grep, find, compare

I have two files tmp1.txt and tmp2.txt
tmp1.txt has

```
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt
ddd.txt
```

tmp2.txt has

```
/tmp/test1/aaa.txt
/tmp/test1/aac.txt
/tmp/test2/bbb.txt
/tmp/test1/ccc.txt
```

I want to check if the files in tmp1.txt exists in tmp2.txt and if it exists display which one it has so it displays something similar to this

```
aaa.txt: test1
bbb.txt: test2
ccc.txt: test1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F/ 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $NF in a {print $NF ": " $(NF-1)}' tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
aaa.txt: test1
bbb.txt: test2
ccc.txt: test1
```

Comment: This works for the example input but will have problems if the paths in `tmp1.txt` can have slashes (and in general other cases where the distinguishing path entry is not the second to last entry). But that is just the result of a (potentially) under-specified problem.

Comment: Yes @EtanReisner: It assumes 2nd file is delimited by `/`.

Comment: It assumes bare filenames in `tmp1.txt` and that the paths in `tmp2.txt` are all of the form `/dont/care/about/this/bit/IMPORTANT/<bare filename from tmp1.txt>`. Which is perfectly reasonable given the sample data in the OP. I just thought it worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose a solution using the standard tools `diff` and `basename`:

```
while read filename
do
    basename "$filename"
done < tmp2.txt > tmp2.basenames.txt
diff -u tmp1.txt tmp2.basenames.txt
```

The main advantage of this solution is its simplicity. The output will look a little different though, differentiating between files in `tmp1.txt`(`-`), `tmp2.txt`(`+`), or both ():

```
--- tmp1.txt    2014-09-17 17:09:43.000000000 +0200
+++ tmp2.basenames.txt  2014-09-17 17:13:12.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 aaa.txt
+aac.txt
 bbb.txt
 ccc.txt
-ddd.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bash Solution:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file && a=$(grep -Fw "$file" tmp2.txt)
do
   echo "$(basename $a): $(dirname $a)"
done < tmp1.txt
```

Comment: This probably wants `-F` and `-w` on that `grep` execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use awk, there's a little bash cycle:

```
while read f; do
  isFound="$(grep /$f tmp2.txt 2>/dev/null)"
  if [ ! -z "$isFound" ]; then
    theDir=$(echo "$isFound"|cut -d'/' -f3)
    echo "$f: $theDir"
  fi
done <tmp1.txt
```