# compare two files in bash with substring

Tags: bash, awk, grep, find, substring

I have two files

tmp1.txt

```
aaa.bbbbb.txt
bbb.aaaaa.txt
ddd.bbbbbb.txt
mmm.cccccc.txt
```

tmp2.txt

```
aaa first
bbb second
ccc third
ddd fourth
eee fifth
fff sixth
```

I want to compare these two files tmp1.txt and tmp2.txt such that first it use anything before the first"." i.e aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd and search that in tmp2.txt and if it finds the match displays as

```
aaa.bbbbb.txt first
bbb.aaaaa.txt second
ddd.bbbbbb.txt fourth
```

Thanks

Comment: anything that you already tried yourself?

Comment: Especially after you've [posted this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894094/compare-two-files-in-bash) you can show an attempted script of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}$1 in a{print $0,a[$1]}' tmp2.txt FS=\. tmp1.txt
aaa.bbbbb.txt first
bbb.aaaaa.txt second
ddd.bbbbbb.txt fourth
```

Use field separator `FS` at the end to have its effect on the file that follows it.

Comment: +1 I was about to post something very similar but setting `FS` between the files is something new

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for the edit. Here is a [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html#Other-Arguments), but I'll be honest, I didn't know it either until I saw [Ed Morton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24517482/970195) use it in one of his answer.

Comment: Why am I not surprised that Ed had something to do with it :)